# MDX-Bundler in Nextjs: Importing Components that import Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

Using [mdx-bundler](https://github.com/kentcdodds/mdx-bundler), can I not import a file which imports another file?

Right now, in my `.mdx` file I do:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

This is my *mdx* file.

<MyComponent />
```

This works, when `<MyComponent />` looks like this:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    return <div>Hello</div>
}

export default MyComponent
```

However, once I import something, it will fail. So when I change `<MyComponent />` to this:

```js
import AnotherBasicComponent from './AnotherBasicComponent'

const MyComponent = () => {
    return <div> 
      <AnotherBasicComponent />
    </div>
}

export default MyComponent
```

I get:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
> at new Function ()
> at getMDXExport (/Users/anton/projects/superdoo/node_modules/.pnpm/mdx-bundler@9.2.1_esbuild@0.15.18/node_modules/mdx-bundler/dist/client.js:44:14)
> at getMDXComponent (/Users/anton/projects/superdoo/node_modules/.pnpm/mdx-bundler@9.2.1_esbuild@0.15.18/node_modules/mdx-bundler/dist/client.js:24:21)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try downgrading esbuild to 0.12.29.

I had a similar problem just now — I was getting the

> Unexpected token '<' at new Function () at getMDXExport

error from my version of `<MyComponent />`, but I wasn't even importing `<AnotherBasicComponent />` into it. The error went away though after implementing [this solution](https://github.com/kentcdodds/mdx-bundler/issues/113#issuecomment-942707516) from mdx-bundler issue 113. I then tested the fix against your situation by importing another basic component into my original component, and everything was still working fine.

In some more detail, here's what I did:

```
// package.json
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "esbuild": "~0.12.29", // downgrade
    "mdx-bundler": "^9.2.1",
    "next": "latest",
    ...
  }
}
```

then `npm install` or `yarn`.

If this does work for you, there might be some more resilient fixes to try. Maybe something could be done with [mdx-bundler's esbuild options](https://github.com/kentcdodds/mdx-bundler#esbuildoptions).